# Why does this code convert numeric data frame columns into string-based factors in a WEIRD way?

Tags: r

I wrote myself a convenience function to replace blank (NA and NULL) values in imported data, but it is behaving very strangely.

Basically, it coerces 0s and 1s to " 0" and " 1" instead of to "0" and "1" (note the added space character)

This is the function

```
replace.blanks = function(dt, value="") {
  return(apply(dt, c(1,2), function(x) { 
    if (is.na(x) || is.null(x)) return(value) else return(x) 
  }))
}
```

Here is code to replicate the result

```
x = data.frame(
      a=c("Wasim", "Jorge", "Kiko", "Jenny"), 
      b=c(1, 0, NA, 1), 
      c=c(0,1,NA, NA)
    )
str(as.data.frame(replace.blanks(x, 0)))
```

Produces

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 4 levels "Jenny","Jorge",..: 4 2 3 1
 $ b: Factor w/ 3 levels " 0"," 1","0": 2 1 3 2
 $ c: Factor w/ 3 levels " 0"," 1","0": 1 2 3 3
```

But if I only have numeric columns

```
y = data.frame(b=c(1, 0, NA, 1), c=c(0,1,NA, NA))
str(as.data.frame(replace.blanks(y, 0)))
```

The same code will produce

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ b: num  1 0 0 1
 $ c: num  0 1 0 0
```

Can anyone explain what is going on? Why are numeric 0s and 1s getting converted to " 0" and " 1" just because one of the columns is of type character?

(edit to clarify my question after useR's response:)
Specifically, why does a 0 in the original become coerced to " 0" and not to "0"? (and the same with 1s becoming " 1" and not "1").

Further, why do I end up with 3 factor levels and not, as one might expect, with 2?

I have basically the same result if I leave the result as a matrix; I am only converting to data frame in the example code to use str

Comment: Unlike dataframes, matrices have to have the same data type for all columns. Your function uses `apply` which returns a matrix, so if only one of your columns is a factor, which `data.frame` automatically converts a string to, all columns get coerced to factors.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that bit out eventually.

But the thing that is weird is that 0 becomes " 0" and not "0". That's what is puzzling me

Answer (score 0):

Unlike dataframes, matrices have to have the same data type for all columns. Your function uses `apply` which returns a matrix, so if only one of your columns is a factor, which `data.frame` automatically converts a string to, all columns get coerced to factors. To check if this is true, try adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your first `data.frame` and see if your result is all `string`

Comment: I tried adding stringsAsFactors to the original data frame, with the same result: a matrix of factors, and 0 » " 0" etc.